# Create a bunch of buttons programmatically in C# Win Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a problem in my C# file. I have to create 6 buttons programmatically on specific  location. but my for loop doesn't work..

just one button shows and not all the buttons.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
//using System.Array;

namespace AimPass
{
     public partial class main : PhoneApplicationPage
     {
    public main()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

private void newbutton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
 // How many buttons do you want ?
        int NumOfButtons = 6;
        // X Location of each created button in the panel
        int loc = 20;
        for (int i = 1; i <= NumOfButtons; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            {
                btn.Name = "Btn-" + i.ToString();
              btn.Size= new Size(50, 20);
               btn.Tag = i;
                btn.Content = "Browse-" + i.ToString();
              btn.location = new Point(5, loc);
            }
            //Add Click event Handler for each created button
           btn.Click += Buttons_Click;
            loc += 20;
            // Add the created btn to grid
            grid.Children.Add(btn);
        }
}

}
```

}

there are 2,3 errors comes..
      using System.Windows.Controls.Buttons    does not contain a definition of location and size...???

```
    btn.Click += Buttons_Click; does not exist in current context..
```

And loop is not working..Just one buttons comes except 6 buttons..

I wanna add button on a specific location..So these errors comes to my requirement..
Thanx in advance for solving this..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time before i have right this ..so take a look you will get what you have read..
it is little bit lengthy but i think it will help you to understand what are you looking for..You can add Row and add button to it in a loop simultaneously but little more is always good..

this is your solution..for your case..but i think you going on wrong way..

```
private void newbutton()
    {
        // How many buttons do you want ?
        int NumOfButtons = 6;
        // X Location of each created button in the panel
        StackPanel stkpanel = new StackPanel();
        stkpanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        int loc = 20;
        for (int i = 1; i <= NumOfButtons; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            {
                btn.Name = "Btn-" + i.ToString();
                btn.Height = 20;
                btn.Width = 50;
                btn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                btn.Content = "btnnum" + i.ToString();
                btn.Tag = i;
                btn.Content = "Browse-" + i.ToString();
                btn.Margin = new Thickness(5 + loc, 5, 5, 5);
                btn.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            }
            //Add Click event Handler for each created button
            btn.Click += btn_Click;
            loc += 20;
            // Add the created btn to grid
            stkpanel.Children.Add(btn);
        }
        grid.Children.Add(stkpanel);
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

**so..it is better you tried something in some sample projects..what i want to canvey to you..
And as the previous answer says button does not contain properties like loc etc that you want to set..for that Margin is thr..and For Size Height and Width are there..and important thing is..first you write Xaml for what you want to achieve and try to set the properties that you set in xaml during in run time in new project..it will definitely tell you how things work..**

```
 Grid grdbooltype = new Grid();
            grdbooltype.Name = "Grid_" + keybooltype;
            grdbooltype.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 20, 0);
            grdbooltype.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            grdbooltype.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

            TextBlock objtextblock = new TextBlock();
            objtextblock.Text = "Select Image";
            objtextblock.FontSize = 15;
            grdbooltype.Children.Add(objtextblock);
            Grid.SetRow(objtextblock, 0);


            Grid grdtoggleswitch = new Grid();
            grdtoggleswitch.Name = headername;
            grdtoggleswitch.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
            grdtoggleswitch.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

            TextBlock txtblktoggleswitchleft = new TextBlock();
            txtblktoggleswitchleft.FontSize = 15;
            txtblktoggleswitchleft.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            txtblktoggleswitchleft.Text = headername;
            Grid.SetColumn(txtblktoggleswitchleft, 0);

            ToggleSwitch toggleswitch = new ToggleSwitch();
            toggleswitch.Name = key;
            toggleswitch.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            toggleswitch.Padding = new Thickness(0);
            toggleswitch.IsOn = defaultvalue;
            toggleswitch.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            toggleswitch.OnContent = "On";
            toggleswitch.OffContent = "Off";
            Grid.SetColumn(toggleswitch, 1);

            grdtoggleswitch.Children.Add(txtblktoggleswitchleft);
            grdtoggleswitch.Children.Add(toggleswitch);

            Grid.SetRow(grdtoggleswitch, 1);

            grdbooltype.Children.Add(grdtoggleswitch);
```

Comment: Krybooltype n other much are also not contain in current context..??what is the possible solution for such type of error..

Comment: You missed the first line I guess. "Grdbooltype" is defined there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, buttons in Windows Phone don't have size nor location. Why would you think that they do? Instead of `Size`, you have two properties: `Width` and `Height`.

As for location, XAML doesn't work that way. Grid is a special kind of control that creates a layout and you define how many columns and rows you want in your grid. Then you place controls *inside* individual cells or you can make controls span cells.

Maybe you should learn a bit about XAML first, here is a good starting point: [Layout for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207042%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

--
EDIT: Adding sample code for placing a button in first row and first column. Note that you have to define grid and column definition either in XAML or code.

```
grid.Children.Add(btn);
Grid.SetRow(btn, 0);
```

Grid.SetColumn(btn, 0);

Comment: do you know syntax of placing my control in grid row or column..??